# Flash AS3 loading swf file into banner

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, banner

I'm trying to make a flash banner that is less than 30K, so I want to create a dummy file, that will be the upper layer and the link to the website, and the lower layer will be calling the SWF file from my source.

I remember doing it once, but I've searched the web (maybe I just couldn't get my Google query right) and didn't find a solution.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a .swf to load another .swf into itself? Use the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class for that.