# open a flash file (swf) from another swf file Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, flash

im currently working on a project for school in ActionScript 3.0 and I need a hub to open different swf files. I've seen people use:

```
var newSwf:String="pong.swf";
var request1:URLRequest = new URLRequest(newSwf);

pong.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onGoToClick);

function onGoToClick(e:Event):void
{
    navigateToURL(request1,'_self');

}
```

but this only works if you open the file on a web browser what i want is to open it from Adobe Flash Player.

Any Answer appreciated. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash AS3 loading swf file into banner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167985/flash-as3-loading-swf-file-into-banner)

Comment: You need a `MovieClip` object to act as a container for the loaded SWF. See if any of these **[Google results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1280&bih=605&noj=1&q=as3+load+external+swf+into+movieclip&oq=as3+%22load+swf+into+another%22&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i71l3.0.0.1.16542.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.B-yHn-ual5Y)** are helpful to you. The **[Flash&Math](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/externalswf/)** link might be most useful if your external SWFs have their own code (ie a game etc) but start with basic loading skills before that one.

Comment: It sounds like you want to load a SWF into a new Standalone Flash Player window? I don't think that's possible. You could use AIR and load the SWF into a new window, though.